# Random forest classifier vastly underperforming comparing to logistic regression, SVM, and naive bayes with cross-validation grid-search?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest

I have a multiclass classification problem. In the cross-validation grid-search to find the best (hyper)parameter settings, I found that the random forest is extremely under-performing (accuracy=0.412, while other ML algo reached 0.70 or higher). I understand this is not necessary a red flag as different ML algorithms may perform best/worst in different problem solution space. But I am wondering if I am not setting the range of its possible hyper-parameter correctly.

```
ml_algo_param_dict = \
                {   
                    'LR_V1': {  'clf': LogisticRegression(),
                                'param': {
                                    'logisticregression__solver': ['liblinear'],
                                    'logisticregression__penalty': ['l1', 'l2'],
                                    'logisticregression__C': np.logspace(-4, 4, 20),
                                    'logisticregression__tol': np.logspace(-5, 5, 20),
                                    'logisticregression__class_weight': [None, 'balanced'],
                                    'logisticregression__multi_class': ['ovr', 'auto'],
                                    'logisticregression__max_iter': [4000, 20000],
                                }},
                    'LR_V2': {  'clf': LogisticRegression(),
                                'param': {
                                    'logisticregression__solver': ['newton-cg', 'lbfgs', 'sag', 'saga'],
                                    'logisticregression__penalty': ['none', 'l2'],
                                    'logisticregression__C': np.logspace(-4, 4, 20),
                                    'logisticregression__tol': np.logspace(-5, 5, 20),
                                    'logisticregression__class_weight': [None, 'balanced'],
                                    'logisticregression__multi_class': ['ovr', 'multinomial', 'auto'],
                                    'logisticregression__max_iter': [4000, 20000],
                                }},
                    'SVC': {    'clf': OneVsRestClassifier(LinearSVC()),
                                'param': {
                                    'onevsrestclassifier__estimator__penalty': ['l2'],
                                    'onevsrestclassifier__estimator__loss': ['hinge', 'squared_hinge'],
                                    'onevsrestclassifier__estimator__C': np.logspace(-4, 4, 20),
                                    'onevsrestclassifier__estimator__tol': np.logspace(-5, 5, 20),
                                    'onevsrestclassifier__estimator__class_weight': [None, 'balanced'],
                                    'onevsrestclassifier__estimator__multi_class': ['ovr', 'crammer_singer'],
                                    'onevsrestclassifier__estimator__max_iter': [50, 1000, 4000, 20000],
                                   }},
                    'RF': {'clf': RandomForestClassifier(),
                                'param': {
                                    'randomforestclassifier__n_estimators': [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 100, 200, 500, ],
                                    'randomforestclassifier__criterion': ['gini', 'entropy'],
                                    'randomforestclassifier__class_weight': [None, 'balanced', 'balanced_subsample'],
                                    'randomforestclassifier__max_depth': np.linspace(1, 10, 32, endpoint=True),
                                    'randomforestclassifier__min_samples_split': np.linspace(0.1, 1.0, 10, endpoint=True),
                                    'randomforestclassifier__min_samples_leaf': np.linspace(0.1, 0.5, 5, endpoint=True),
                                    'randomforestclassifier__max_leaf_nodes': [None, 50, 100, 200, 400],
                                    'randomforestclassifier__max_features': [None, 'auto', 'sqrt', 'log2'],
                                }},
                    'NB': {'clf': BernoulliNB(),
                                'param': {
                                    'bernoullinb__alpha': np.logspace(-4, 4, 20),
                                    'bernoullinb__binarize': [None, 0, .2, .4, .6, .8, 1],
                                    'bernoullinb__fit_prior': [True, False],
                                }},
                }
```

Result

```
>> Best score: 0.712
>> Best parameter:
Pipeline(memory=None,
         steps=[('columntransformer',
                 ColumnTransformer(n_jobs=None, remainder='drop',
                                   sparse_threshold=0.3,
                                   transformer_weights=None,
                                   transformers=[('num',
                                                  Pipeline(memory=None,
                                                           steps=[('imputer',
                                                                   SimpleImputer(add_indicator=False,
                                                                                 copy=True,
                                                                                 fill_value=None,
                                                                                 missing_values=nan,
                                                                                 strategy='median',
                                                                                 verbose=0)),
                                                                  ('scaler',
                                                                   StandardScaler(copy=True,
                                                                                  with...
                                                           verbose=False),
                                                  ['LOC_ENTITY_LIST'])],
                                   verbose=False)),
                ('logisticregression',
                 LogisticRegression(C=0.03359818286283781,
                                    class_weight='balanced', dual=False,
                                    fit_intercept=True, intercept_scaling=1,
                                    l1_ratio=None, max_iter=4000,
                                    multi_class='ovr', n_jobs=None,
                                    penalty='l2', random_state=None,
                                    solver='liblinear', tol=1e-05, verbose=0,
                                    warm_start=False))],
         verbose=False)
>> Best selected parameter:
{'logisticregression__tol': 1e-05, 'logisticregression__solver': 'liblinear', 'logisticregression__penalty': 'l2', 'logisticregression__multi_class': 'ovr',   'logisticregression__max_iter': 4000, 'logisticregression__class_weight': 'balanced', 'logisticregression__C': 0.03359818286283781}  

>> Best score: 0.738
>> Best parameter:
Pipeline(memory=None,
         steps=[('columntransformer',
                 ColumnTransformer(n_jobs=None, remainder='drop',
                                   sparse_threshold=0.3,
                                   transformer_weights=None,
                                   transformers=[('num',
                                                  Pipeline(memory=None,
                                                           steps=[('imputer',
                                                                   SimpleImputer(add_indicator=False,
                                                                                 copy=True,
                                                                                 fill_value=None,
                                                                                 missing_values=nan,
                                                                                 strategy='median',
                                                                                 verbose=0)),
                                                                  ('scaler',
                                                                   StandardScaler(copy=True,
                                                                                  with...
                                                           verbose=False),
                                                  ['LOC_ENTITY_LIST'])],
                                   verbose=False)),
                ('logisticregression',
                 LogisticRegression(C=0.23357214690901212, class_weight=None,
                                    dual=False, fit_intercept=True,
                                    intercept_scaling=1, l1_ratio=None,
                                    max_iter=20000, multi_class='ovr',
                                    n_jobs=None, penalty='l2',
                                    random_state=None, solver='lbfgs',
                                    tol=0.01438449888287663, verbose=0,
                                    warm_start=False))],
         verbose=False)
>> Best selected parameter:
{'logisticregression__tol': 0.01438449888287663, 'logisticregression__solver': 'lbfgs', 'logisticregression__penalty': 'l2', 'logisticregression__multi_class': 'ovr',   'logisticregression__max_iter': 20000, 'logisticregression__class_weight': None, 'logisticregression__C': 0.23357214690901212}  

>> Best score: 0.708
>> Best parameter:
Pipeline(memory=None,
         steps=[('columntransformer',
                 ColumnTransformer(n_jobs=None, remainder='drop',
                                   sparse_threshold=0.3,
                                   transformer_weights=None,
                                   transformers=[('num',
                                                  Pipeline(memory=None,
                                                           steps=[('imputer',
                                                                   SimpleImputer(add_indicator=False,
                                                                                 copy=True,
                                                                                 fill_value=None,
                                                                                 missing_values=nan,
                                                                                 strategy='median',
                                                                                 verbose=0)),
                                                                  ('scaler',
                                                                   StandardScaler(copy=True,
                                                                                  with...
                                                           verbose=False),
                                                  ['LOC_ENTITY_LIST'])],
                                   verbose=False)),
                ('onevsrestclassifier',
                 OneVsRestClassifier(estimator=LinearSVC(C=78.47599703514607,
                                                         class_weight='balanced',
                                                         dual=True,
                                                         fit_intercept=True,
                                                         intercept_scaling=1,
                                                         loss='hinge',
                                                         max_iter=4000,
                                                         multi_class='ovr',
                                                         penalty='l2',
                                                         random_state=None,
                                                         tol=3.359818286283781e-05,
                                                         verbose=0),
                                     n_jobs=None))],
         verbose=False)
>> Best selected parameter:
{'onevsrestclassifier__estimator__tol': 3.359818286283781e-05, 'onevsrestclassifier__estimator__penalty': 'l2', 'onevsrestclassifier__estimator__multi_class': 'ovr',   'onevsrestclassifier__estimator__max_iter': 4000, 'onevsrestclassifier__estimator__loss': 'hinge', 'onevsrestclassifier__estimator__class_weight': 'balanced',   'onevsrestclassifier__estimator__C': 78.47599703514607}  

>> Best score: 0.412
>> Best parameter:
Pipeline(memory=None,
         steps=[('columntransformer',
                 ColumnTransformer(n_jobs=None, remainder='drop',
                                   sparse_threshold=0.3,
                                   transformer_weights=None,
                                   transformers=[('num',
                                                  Pipeline(memory=None,
                                                           steps=[('imputer',
                                                                   SimpleImputer(add_indicator=False,
                                                                                 copy=True,
                                                                                 fill_value=None,
                                                                                 missing_values=nan,
                                                                                 strategy='median',
                                                                                 verbose=0)),
                                                                  ('scaler',
                                                                   StandardScaler(copy=True,
                                                                                  with...
                 RandomForestClassifier(bootstrap=True, class_weight=None,
                                        criterion='gini',
                                        max_depth=6.806451612903226,
                                        max_features=None, max_leaf_nodes=50,
                                        min_impurity_decrease=0.0,
                                        min_impurity_split=None,
                                        min_samples_leaf=0.2,
                                        min_samples_split=0.2,
                                        min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0,
                                        n_estimators=200, n_jobs=None,
                                        oob_score=False, random_state=None,
                                        verbose=0, warm_start=False))],
         verbose=False)
>> Best selected parameter:
{'randomforestclassifier__n_estimators': 200, 'randomforestclassifier__min_samples_split': 0.2, 'randomforestclassifier__min_samples_leaf': 0.2,   'randomforestclassifier__max_leaf_nodes': 50, 'randomforestclassifier__max_features': None, 'randomforestclassifier__max_depth': 6.80645161290322  6,   'randomforestclassifier__criterion': 'gini', 'randomforestclassifier__class_weight': None}  

>> Best score: 0.697
>> Best parameter:
Pipeline(memory=None,
         steps=[('columntransformer',
                 ColumnTransformer(n_jobs=None, remainder='drop',
                                   sparse_threshold=0.3,
                                   transformer_weights=None,
                                   transformers=[('num',
                                                  Pipeline(memory=None,
                                                           steps=[('imputer',
                                                                   SimpleImputer(add_indicator=False,
                                                                                 copy=True,
                                                                                 fill_value=None,
                                                                                 missing_values=nan,
                                                                                 strategy='median',
                                                                                 verbose=0)),
                                                                  ('scaler',
                                                                   StandardScaler(copy=True,
                                                                                  with...
                                                                                   lowercase=True,
                                                                                   max_df=1.0,
                                                                                   max_features=5000,
                                                                                   min_df=1,
                                                                                   ngram_range=(1,
                                                                                                1),
                                                                                   preprocessor=None,
                                                                                   stop_words=None,
                                                                                   strip_accents=None,
                                                                                   token_pattern='(?u)\\b\\w\\w+\\b',
                                                                                   tokenizer=None,
                                                                                   vocabulary=None))],
                                                           verbose=False),
                                                  ['LOC_ENTITY_LIST'])],
                                   verbose=False)),
                ('bernoullinb',
                 BernoulliNB(alpha=0.00026366508987303583, binarize=0.6,
                             class_prior=None, fit_prior=True))],
         verbose=False)
>> Best selected parameter:
{'bernoullinb__fit_prior': True, 'bernoullinb__binarize': 0.6, 'bernoullinb__alpha': 0.00026366508987303583}
```

Any suggestion of what to do/test next and the explanation of why this is the case will be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In machine learning and deep learning for either discrete/generative model, we always think and remember what **Occam Razor** said, `“when presented with competing hypothetical answers to a problem, one should select the one that makes the fewest assumptions”`. Which can be translated as:

- Models with least complexity (i.e. hyper-parameters, features, etc.) tend to perform better than one with higher complexity.
- It is always recommend to start with least complex model and then partially increase toward more elaborates one (with higher hyper-parameters, more assumptions, etc.)

A **Random Forest** is already a very complex model, which involves a [bagging ensemble method](https://www.kdnuggets.com/2017/10/random-forests-explained.html) of multiple **Decision Trees**.

My recommendation would be to try a very simple Decision Tree and update its hyper -parameters if you can obtain a better or similar performance than you other models, then I will try add more complexity and very simple RF with minimal hyper-parameters such as `2 < randomforestclassifier__max_leaf_node < 10`